# Unable to Send or Receive MMS on LineageOS on T-Mobile S6

Tags: lineageos, mms, 9.0-pie

NexusOS 9.0 (LineageOS for Galaxy S6 T-Mobile)

MMS sending hangs Messenger

MMS receiving downloads forever

Comment: Verify you have the most up to date APN with T-mobile customer service.

Comment: @BoLawson that was the problem, it was just an APN setting wrong, I checked in the docs

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to

Settings > Network > APN > Hold finger down on current APN setting

and change **APN Protocol** from `IPv6` to `IPv4/IPv6` per [T-Mobiles APN Docs](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-2090)

*NB: I also downloaded the T-Mobile and T-Mobile Visual Voicemail app and switched from LineageOS messenger app to Textra, but I doubt those steps were relevant.*